# SQL Help - Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXISTS'

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having issues with my sql (I am relatively new to sql). I cannot figure out why I am getting a syntax error. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name_1
WHERE
column_A IN ('Lorem', 'Ipsum', 'Test') 
AND column_B NOT EXISTS
    (
    SELECT column_C 
    FROM table_name_2
    WHERE Date  >= CURDATE()
    )
```

Comment: please tag `mysql`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot compare NOT EXISTS with a column value.

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name_1
WHERE
column_A IN ('Lorem', 'Ipsum', 'Test') 
AND NOT EXISTS
    (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM table_name_2
    WHERE Date  >= CURDATE()
    AND column_c = column_b
    )
```

or use IN

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name_1
WHERE
column_A IN ('Lorem', 'Ipsum', 'Test') 
AND column_B NOT IN
    (
    SELECT column_C 
    FROM table_name_2
    WHERE Date  >= CURDATE()
    )
```

Comment: careful when using IN or NOT IN when a column contains null values. see below post for more info: https://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2007/01/21/32/